# Notepad++ on windows10 showing whitespace wrong

Tags: python, terminal, notepad++

I am getting indent errors all the time because np++ is displaying whitespaces wrong.

Here is picture of np++ compared to editing from terminal(look whitespaces below save function):

[image]

Any ideas what might be wrong ?

Edit: Picture showing tabs, spaces... 
[image]

Comment: You're using tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: `View` => `Show Symbol` => `Show white Space and TAB` Don't mix spaces and tab.

Comment: Any idea how to change this to show correctly ? I tried settings and tab=4 spaces but that doesn't seem to be it.

Comment: @Gall I edited question with another picture, for sure this is not some other kind of issue ? 

And any ideas how to fix this? Before I used win10 it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yep, you need to only use spaces OR tabs. You can try `Edit` => `Blank Operations` to convert the document but I think np++ does not handle very well spaces to tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all tips, @Gall was right in comments it was tabs/spaces issue and it was solved by going to settings->Preferences->Tab Settings

And choosing Python + Replace by space

Answer (score 0):

You should also change the tab size of nano then:

Edit your ~/.nanorc file (or create it) and add:

```
set tabsize 4
```

Or to convert them to spaces:

```
set tabstospaces
```